How do you return empty field for time in the asp.net side
I can do this for a date
Text= '<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("AddDate")) !=  Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/0001") ? Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("AddDate")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") : "" %>'

Which evaluates where the date is 01/01/0001 and if it is it sets the label to blank/empty as in nothing there.
Is there a way to do this for a Time field from SQL?
The time returning for and empty dataset is 00:00:00 and if it is that I dont want it to show on the form.  The above errors for Time and the below also doesnt work.
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCheckin" runat="server" Text='<%# DateTime.ParseExact(Eval("StartTime")) !=  DateTime.ParseExact("00:00:00") ? DateTime.ParseExact(Eval("StartTime")).ToString("hh:mm") : "" %>'    />  


What error(s) do you get from the code shown?  What specifically "doesn't work" about it?

the error in this case doesnt matter since i am asking for a specific thing.. I wanted to know how to not show time -- that was the question

this was the fix to remove empty time you can eval to look for a certain time and if it = the time then it wont show.
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtCheckout" runat="server" TextMode="Time" Text='<%# (Eval("EndTime").ToString()) != ("00:00:00") ? (Eval("EndTime"))  : "" %>'  />
                                                


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
